# Android Tablets/Galaxy tab not detect as a tablet in WURFL

Tags: android, wurfl, mobile-devices

I used `wurfl-2.3.3` WURFL File and checked my site with Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 and it identifies the device as a mobile phone but if I check it with Ipad it correctly identifies it as a tablet.

FYI, the following is the script I used.

```
$is_tablet = ($requestingDevice->getCapability('is_tablet') == 'true');
$is_phone = ($requestingDevice->getCapability('can_assign_phone_number') == 'true');

if ($is_tablet) {
echo "This is a Tablet";
} else if ($is_phone) {
echo "This is a Mobile Phone";
}
```

Is all Android tablets use user agent as 'mobile'? How to fix this problem and which make sure WURFL can identifies all android tablets as a tablet not a mobile(including samsung) ?

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have extensively tested the Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10.1, Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, Samsung Activ Tab, iPhone5, iPad Mini, iPad Retina & iPad2 using a similar php with the Cloud WURFL...

```
$wireless = ($client->getDeviceCapability('is_wireless_device'));   
$tablet = ($client->getDeviceCapability('is_tablet'));

if ($tablet){
    echo "This is a tablet device";
} elseif ($wireless && !$tablet) {  
    echo "This is a mobile device"; 
}...
```

I have found that both the Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10.1 & Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, are confused about their identites. Having tried several of each device, some redirect to 'tablet' & some redirect to 'mobile'. There is no consistency!

The iPad/iPhone devices all behave as they should (...& I'm a PC/Android user)!!

Have the Samsung devices undergone recent upgrades not recorded in the WURFL?